# How to read variable value when it changes when creating an object?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the class UnZip below that unzip files, as it unzips, the name of the uncompressed files are output to the variable **destinationPath**

```
public class UnZip {

public void unzip(String filename) throws IOException {

...
...

    try {

        ...
        ...

            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Extracting file: " + destinationPath);


                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));

                int b;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

                ...
                ...

                bos.close();
                bis.close();

            }

        }

    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error opening zip file" + ioe);
    }
     finally {
         try {
             if (zipFile!=null) {
                 zipFile.close();
             }
         }
         catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing zip file" + ioe);
         }
     }
}
```

Here is my main class, I create an UnZip object called unzipper to start to inzip the file **zipFilePath**. Here is my problem, as I create the unzipper object and the procedure of the class is executed, I wanted to output the name of each file that is being uncompressed, as denoted by the variable **destinationPath** from the UnZip class. Is there any desgin pattern I could use to achieve this?

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

...
...

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window frame = new Window();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Window() {


                UnZip unzipper = new UnZip();
                try {
                    unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath);
                    //I wants to print the file name here
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // some errors occurred
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).  This would allow you to attach an `interface` to the `UnZip` class which would call one or methods which provide information to interested parties.

These are often call "listeners" in Swing